# Upload and Display Image in Django Rest Framework via FileField or ImageField

Tags: django, image, api, file, django-rest-framework

I want to upload an image to my Django Rest API and click the link I get and then see the actual image (like any other image on the internet), this is so I can then display the image in my mobile app.

This is my code:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Assignments'

def __str__(self):
    return "{name}".format(name=self.name)

class AssignmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Assignment
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'image')

class AssignmentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Assignment.objects.all()
serializer_class = AssignmentSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('assignments', views.AssignmentView),


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/', include('example.urls')),
]

//Settings
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

When I click an image in the Rest API I get en error! {"detail":"Not found."}

Comment: What does the API return? Your serializer references "image" but that field does not exist on your model

Comment: Are you at least seeing the uploaded file in your media directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your serializer, add a custom method that returns the URL from the file field

```
class AssignmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Assignment
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image', 'url')

    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_url')

    def get_url(self, assignment):
        return assignment.file.url
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with your code in my local PC, there is only one error that I get, and it is:

```
Field name `image` is not valid for model `Assignment`.
```

which arose from your serializer. You declare the field name `file` in your model and tried to get a field named `image`. Though you can change the original field name in your serializer by following way:

```
image = serializers.FileField(source='file')
```

And thus your serializer class will be as following:

```
class AssignmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.FileField(source='file')

    class Meta:
        model = Assignment
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image')
```

Otherwise, just keep the field name as same as the model.

I've tried with your code and I found both file and image in my directory and also can browse those files.

If you still face any problem, try with the following lines of code in your `models.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

image_storage = FileSystemStorage(
    # Physical file location ROOT
    location='{0}/'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
    # Url for file
    base_url='{0}/'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL),
)

def file_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'files/{0}'.format(filename)

class Assignment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_directory_path, storage=image_storage, blank=False,null=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Assignments'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{name}".format(name=self.name)
```